# Google BigQuery: Data drop when streaming insert right after copy to same table with WRITE_TRUNCATE

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I hope I can make it as clear as possible to understand. I am maintaining data regarding stage movements i.e. when someone moves into stage and when someone moves out. I want bigquery table to have single entry for each stage movement(due to the kind of query I'll be doing on the data) but there are two updates for in and out and so this is what I am doing;

1. Normal Streaming insert when someone moves into stage
2. While Moving out:

   a. Copy the truncated table to the same destination using a query like

   ```
   SELECT * FROM my_dataset.my_table WHERE id !="id"
   ```

   b. Do a streaming insert for the new row.

The problem is, there are random data drops when doing streaming inserts after the copy operation.

I found this link: [After recreating BigQuery table streaming inserts are not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415265/after-recreating-bigquery-table-streaming-inserts-are-not-working)

where it has been mentioned that there should be a delay of >2mins before doing streaming inserts in this case to avoid data drops but, I want it to be instantaneous since multiple stage movements can be happening in a matter of a few seconds. Is there a workaround or a fix for this? Or do I have to rethink my complete process in an append-only basis which isn't looking likely right now?

Answer (score 0):

> do I have to rethink my complete process in an append-only basis?

My suggestion for your particular case would be not to truncate table on each and every “move out”.

Assuming you have field that identifies recent row (timestamp or order, etc.) you can easily filter out old rows with something like

```
SELECT <your_fileds> 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    <your_fileds>, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestanp DESC) AS most_recent_row
  FROM my_dataset.my_table 
)
WHERE most_recent_row = 1
```

If needed you can do daily purging of "old/not latest" rows into truncated table using the very same approach as above

> where it has been mentioned?

Maybe not that explicitly your case, but check [Data availability](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability) section
And in [How to change the template table schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#how_to_change_the_template_table_schema) read third paragraph (I feel it is related)