# Reliability of streaming in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a problem I do not understand even if I see the potential underlying problem.

I want to create a table at date T, stream data inside it.
The following day, I delete the table at date T, create a new table at date T+1 and then stream data.
Etc.

The problem occurs between the table creation and the streaming.
Indeed, sometimes I stream data and nothing is actually streamed. It is generally when I delete a table at date T and recreate it directly.

Is there a lag between table deletion and actual reference deletion ?
Sometimes Google tells me that the table does not exist...in fact it exists.

I do it with Java. The compilation seems ver fast but the actual reference seems long to arrive.

I put a Thread/sleep of 2 minutes bewteen the operations and still...
I can wait 10 minutes or more but will it be 100% reliable ?

Thanks

Comment: I asked something similar a while ago and this is an expected behavior in bigquery: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846571/bigquery-table-truncation-before-streaming-not-working
Partitioned tables might suit you well in this case (it didn't help us though as we can't stream data in decorated tables, so we just kept creating tables everyday)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a current limitation around the scenario you mentioned and we hope to resolve in the future.

I gather from your post that you are using daily tables? Have you considered the possibility of using partitioned tables. Data will automatically get into the latest day's partition. You may also set an expiration on the data. If you would like to remove data from a partition manually, you can do a query with allow_large_results and WRITE_TRUNCATE to the partition as the destination.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so I was not dreaming ^^ Thanks also for the tip, I use it and create the next table one day before so that the table is available for next day. i also saw that my code did not really evaluate and so return streaming response on Clojure, I solved it too now the automation work