# BigQuery python client library dropping data on insert_rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the Python API to write to BigQuery -- I've had success previously, but I'm pretty novice with the BigQuery platform.

I recently updated a table schema to include some new nested records. After creating this new table, I'm seeing significant portions of data not making it to BigQuery.

However, *some* of the data is coming through. In a single write statement, my code will try to send through a handful of rows. Some of the rows make it and some do not, but no errors are being thrown from the BigQuery endpoint.

I have access to the stackdriver logs for this project and there are no errors or warnings indicating that a write would have failed. I'm not streaming the data -- using the BigQuery client library to call the API endpoint (I saw other answers that state issues with streaming data to a newly created table).

Has anyone else had issues with the BigQuery API? I haven't found any documentation stating about a delay to access the data (I found the opposite -- supposed to be near real-time, right?) and I'm not sure what's causing the issue at this point.

Any help or reference would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Apparently the API *is* the streaming API -- missed on my part.

Edit2: [This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444853/bigquery-streamed-data-is-not-in-table) is related. Though, I've been writing to the table every 5 minutes for about 24 hours, and I'm still seeing missing data. I'm curious if writing to a BigQuery table within 10 minutes of it's creation puts you in a permanent state of losing data or if it would be expected to catching everything after the initial 10 minutes from creation.

Comment: The response from the API should contain [the errors that happened during insertion](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll#response). Can you print them out and add them to the question? (Remove any PII from them)

Comment: That's one of my issues -- I'm not getting any errors, the result from the API call is showing as being completely successful. For all intents and purposes, it looks completely fine, except for the part where the values are actually in the table after the write.

Comment: Could you provide a specific example of what did you insert and what got written? This will help to understand/reproduce the issue. About Edit2: are you performing delete/create operations in the table? This is not clear for me...; if you are, add `import sleep`, `time.sleep(300)` to check if it improves the rate of data saved.

Comment: About the 2nd edit, yesterday I answered [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51028246) related to that. I think the discussion on those related questions is about deleting and re-creating tables, not staight away creation. I've run tests with create and direct insert, and they worked for me. Furthermore, the delete+re-create process, as of my testing yesterday, had a delay of <10s from table creation, but this could be related to the region and schema used (EU, single BYTES field).