# Why UPDATE or DELETE statement over table would affect rows in the streaming buffer, is not supported and how to fix it?

Tags: java, sql, google-bigquery, sql-delete

I'm writing data has read from datastore to bigquery using cloud function will that run every 1 hour, but I need to delete all rows before rewriting which is not allowed because of buffering:

```
BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
            //Table table = bigquery.getTable(TableId.of(DATASET, TABLE_NAME));
            if (bigquery.getTable(TableId.of(DATASET, TABLE_NAME)) != null) {
                QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig =
                        QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(
                                        "DELETE FROM `" + DATASET + "." + TABLE_NAME + "` WHERE true;")
                                .build();
                JobId jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                Job queryJob = bigquery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).setJobId(jobId).build());
                queryJob = queryJob.waitFor();
                // Check for errors
                if (queryJob == null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Job no longer exists");
                } else if (queryJob.getStatus().getError() != null) {
                    // You can also look at queryJob.getStatus().getExecutionErrors() for all
                    // errors, not just the latest one.
                    throw new RuntimeException(queryJob.getStatus().getError().toString());
                }
            } else {
                Field id = Field.of("id", StandardSQLTypeName.INT64);
                Field name = Field.of("name", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING);
                Schema schema = Schema.of(id, name);
                TableId tableId = TableId.of(DATASET, TABLE_NAME);
                TableDefinition tableDefinition = StandardTableDefinition.of(schema);
                TableInfo tableInfo = TableInfo.newBuilder(tableId, tableDefinition).build();
                bigquery.create(tableInfo);
            }

            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : campaign.entrySet()) {
                row.set("id", entry.getKey()).set("name", entry.getValue());
                bigquery.insertAll(InsertAllRequest.newBuilder(TableId.of(DATASET, TABLE_NAME)).addRow(row).build());
            }
```

This excutes runtime error :

> "UPDATE or DELETE statement over table would affect rows in the
> streaming buffer, which is not supported"

Comment: You can use **TRUNCATE TABLE** instead of **DELETE ... WHERE TRUE**. Or you can use **create table YOUR_TABLE as select * from YOUR_TALBE limit 0**. These examples clear table. But when re-creating or truncating a table "You'll need to wait >2 minutes before streaming in order to avoid data being dropped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846571/bigquery-table-truncation-before-streaming-not-working

Comment: The main point is: if your streaming buffer is not empty than you can't clear the table fast, you have to wait a few minutes after clearing.

Comment: Hi @Mohamed Haydar, Did the above comment help?

Comment: I don't think it did, I believe you need to wait the streaming buffer which will take about 90 min so I run my cloud function every 2 hours and it works.

Comment: Hi @MohamedHaydar , According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability),the streaming buffer and streamed rows might not be available for table copy typically for a few minutes to 90 minutes.Due to this the error mentioned is occurring. You need to wait until the table is cleared. Let me know if that helps.