# BigQuery Streaming - what happens when we WRITE_TRUNCATE?

Tags: google-bigquery

We are trying to debug a situation where some rows did not make it into BigQuery that we expected. We see no errors or warnings and believe that our streaming insert call succeeded.  with python, we run `bigquery.tabledata().insertAll` and see no `insertErrors` in the response.

While streaming rows, we also have a job that checks for duplicates and fixes them, by creating a materialized view and replacing our table with that:

```
insert_request = bigquery.jobs().insert(
        projectId=project_id,
        # https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#resource
        body={
            "configuration": {
                "query": {
                    "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",  # overwrite
                    "query": query,
                    "useQueryCache": True,
                    "useLegacySql": legacy_sql,
                    "destinationTable": {
                        "projectId": project_id,
                        "datasetId": dataset_id,
                        "tableId": table_name
                    },
                }
            }
        })

job = insert_request.execute()
check_job_status(bigquery, job)
```

is it possible that the rows we are streaming, and are in the buffer, are being dropped in the process of deduping?

Comment: just to add additional context, we were missing about half of the rows we were expecting - it was a huge differential between what we thought we streamed, and what we saw in bigquery.  we know that we ran a deduping process (the one above) in the midst of our streaming this data.

Comment: it looks like the answer is "yes": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415265/after-recreating-bigquery-table-streaming-inserts-are-not-working/36417177#36417177