# Streaming data into BigQuery fresh new table?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I am using the Java API for google BigQuery to stream real-time event logs into the database.

Since the structure of the events is not known in advance, I need to perform a live creation of the tables in java when the events start coming.

This is made by a call to `bigQuery.create( tableInfo )`. This call is synchronous and right after this call, the table is created with the expected structure, according to the BigQuery Web console.

However, when I try to stream data into this freshly created table by

```
bigQuery.insertAll(request);
```

a `BigQueryException` is raised with message `Not found: Table myProject.myDataset.myNewTableName` while the table actually exists !
After waiting a few seconds (approximately 30 seconds), the streaming starts working properly.
Moreover, the problem occurs even if a call to `bigQuery.listtables(dataset, tableListOptions)` confirms from the server that the table exists !

After a look at the google documentation,

> After you change a template table schema, wait until the changes have propagated before you try to insert new data or query generated tables. Requests to insert new fields should succeed within a few minutes. Attempts to query the new fields might require a longer wait of up to 90 minutes.

Is this the reason why ? Is it a normal behavior that the streaming insert cannot work on a new table ? Is there a workaround ?

Any thoughts about this situation will be welcomed.

Thank you ;)

Comment: For BQ engineers who will read this: Also you should have a webhook notifying us when it's propagated, and we can start using it.

Comment: Are you running insertAll before the tables are created? insertAll caches error responses for 5 minutes, so you will have to wait 5 minutes before streaming to a new table.

Comment: @TimSwast where is this 5 minutes documented/mentioned?

Comment: @TimSwast Indeed, I am running insertAll that returns a normal error before tables are created. I made some research about this caching of insertAll, are you talking about a client-side cache for this request ? I can't find any piece of documentation that mentions that. Moreover, the delay in my case is shorter than 5 minutes. Is there a way to somehow disable any kind of caching for a request ? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I guess it's one minute. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/issues/1635#issuecomment-327543698 Though Felipe says about 2 minutes here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36861318/101923 for a similar problem. I'll file an issue to document the cache time on insertAll requests.

Comment: @TimSwast thank you very much for your answer. It seems that there is not much I can do about this issue except wait for the cache to invalidate to resend the data. A streaming insert with a "create table if not exists" parameter or something like that would be a very nice feature for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After recreating BigQuery table streaming inserts are not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415265/after-recreating-bigquery-table-streaming-inserts-are-not-working)